# Info file emacs does not exist

Tags: documentation, help

When I type <kbd>C-h r</kbd> I get error:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Info file emacs does not exist")
>   signal(error ("Info file emacs does not exist"))   error("Info file %s
>   does not exist" "emacs")   Info-find-file("emacs")
>   Info-find-node("emacs" "Top")   Info-goto-node("(emacs)")
>   info-setup("emacs" #)   info("emacs")
>   info-emacs-manual()   call-interactively(info-emacs-manual nil nil)

I am using Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. (I have installed package `emacs24-common-non-dfsg`.. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the correct path to the Emacs info files in the `INFOPATH` environment variable:

```
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/share/info/emacs-24
```

Answer (score 16):

That error is because the full documentation is not installed by default.

Solve it by installing `emacs25-common-non-dfsg`

```
# aptitude install emacs25-common-non-dfsg
```

Test it by trying,

```
C-h i h
```

It should now work.

Comment: It is interesting to know that GNU Free Documentation License (GFDL) is [at odds](https://www.debian.org/vote/2006/vote_001) with Debian Free Software Guidelines (DFSG).  This is the reason why it is not included in the first place.

Comment: Update in 2023 - Ubuntu 22.04, installed Elisp docs with `apt install emacs-common-non-dfsg`. From https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/emacs-common-non-dfsg

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to build [Emacs from source](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html#gnu-linux): you get not only full Emacs documentation but also a more recent version, presently 27.1 instead of 26.3 (in Ubuntu 20.10).

Configure is straightforward because all the dependencies can be obtianed with: `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs`.

Add to $INFOPATH: `/usr/local/share/info /usr/share/info/emacs /usr/share/info`.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10. The non-dfsg stuff does not exist in apt.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting INFOPATH didn't solve it for me.

I'm running Debian 9.4 derived Bunsen Helium. Somehow, I didn't get info,
or the Emacs info files installed. So:
Set INFOPATH in .bashrc:

```
export INFOPATH=/usr/share/info
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/share/info/emacs
```

Then installed info:

```
$ sudo apt-get install info
```

Then downloaded these gnu info files and installed them in directory
/usr/share/info/emacs
(did it as root)
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/info/emacs.info.gz
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/info/elisp.info.gz

Finally, upgraded my emacs version (got me up to Emacs 25.2.2):

```
$ sudo apt-get install emacs
```

Not sure if all this was the 'right' way to do it, but I'm tired of fooling with it...

Comment: Did you install the `emacs25-common-non-dfsg` package?

Comment: Just tried it. Way easier than what I was doing. Seems to put the info files in: /usr/share/info/emacs-25. Still need

Comment: It's really unfortunate, but Debian sees certain usage of the GNU Free Documentation License as non-free by their own definitions, and consequently installs Emacs (and doubtless other packages) without the documentation (which of course is really a crucial component of the application). Which explains why it's in a separate package (and the `non-dfsg` suffix).  Refer to https://www.linux.com/news/debian-decides-gnu-free-documentation-license

Comment: Tried to edit my comment, but some stupid 5 minute limit just tossed it...