# C-h i *info* directory is nearly empty

Tags: documentation, info

My situation is similar to [Info file emacs does not exist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/info-file-emacs-does-not-exist). I installed `emacs24`, `emacs24-el`, and `emacs24-common-non-dfsg` on Ubuntu 14.04. Unlike in that other question, <kbd>C-h r</kbd> *does* work for me and I do get the "Emacs" manual.

However from using Emacs on OS X, I'm accustomed to <kbd>C-h i</kbd> bringing up a full directory of many, many topics. Instead, my directory only has three nodes, for a few packages that provide info files (Flycheck, Haskell Mode, and Magit).

`(Info-default-dirs)` evaluates to `("/usr/share/info/emacs-24" "/usr/share/info/" "/usr/share/info/")`.  I do see all the individual info.gz files in `/usr/share/info/emacs-24`. I can open them individually, for example `(info "/usr/share/info/emacs-24/elisp.info.gz")` *does* bring up the "Emacs Lisp" node.

But again, I'm accustomed to <kbd>C-h i</kbd> bringing up the full directory. I don't know much about info files. How can I make this work?

Comment: What is the value of `Info-directory-list`?

Comment: If you run info from the command line, do you get the same result?

Comment: @rekado It's `("/home/greg/.emacs.d/elpa/flycheck-20150412.242" "/home/greg/.emacs.d/elpa/haskell-mode-20150412.1138" "/home/greg/.emacs.d/elpa/magit-20150411.1731" "/usr/share/info/emacs-24" "/usr/share/info/" "/usr/share/info/")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds as if the `dir` file within your info directories don't contain all the nodes that it should. You can verify this by looking at the contents of the file `/usr/share/info/emacs-24/dir` (if this is the directory that's lacking entries).

Normally, this file will be updated by the program that installs the info file, but you can also do it manually. If the info directory that is missing entries is `/usr/share/info/emacs-24`, you can create the dir entries by running

```
cd /usr/share/info/emacs-24
for i in *info*; do install-info $i dir; done
```

Comment: Thanks! `/usr/share/info/emacs-24` lacked any `dir` file. Also, `install-info` wasn't found. (If it had been, maybe the `apt-get install emacs-24-common-non-dfsg` would have updated the `dir`.) I installed the `info` package, followed your instructions, and now all is well.  (p.s. This is Ubuntu from crouton on a Chromebook. I'm realizing the initial config is fairly minimal. On the bright side, I'm learning more. :))

Comment: I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 7):

`C-h i` runs the `info` command by default, which searches for info files in `Info-directory-list`.  If this is nil Info uses the environment variable `INFOPATH` or `Info-default-directory-list` if no `INFOPATH` variable is defined.

When the info files are not found it is possible that one or more of these values has been incorrectly customised.

Comment: You can also add paths to `Info-additional-directory-list`.