# How to add additional info manuals to emacs' collection

Tags: osx, info

Is there an easy way to supplement emacs' info manual with additional nodes?

Or does one have to go through http://www.gnu.org/manual/manual.html to download manuals, and then manually insert them into emacs?
This seems pretty tedious, especially since there are numerous documents that I would like to add. (gdb, C, gcc, djvu package, etc.)

On the same line, I have installed gdb through homebrew (on OS X Yosemite) but still when I run the command "info gdb" in the terminal it brings me to the man pages. Shouldn't info pages come packaged with GNU installations by default?

**EDIT**

What I meant by "an easy way" was an interface through emacs or likewise such as that for packages (*package-list-packages* function in emacs).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C-h i \*info\* directory is nearly empty](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10814/c-h-i-info-directory-is-nearly-empty)

Comment: I was wrong. It appears that info manuals DO in fact come with the respective program's installation. I figured this out when I reinstalled gdb through the GNU website.

I believe that when I first installed gdb I used homebrew.
Could it be that homebrew does not install info packages?