# Info files are found but not installed (on archlinux)

Tags: info, install

I am not able to access many info files. For example, the command `(info "(gnus) Sorting the Summary Buffer")` returns

> Info file gnus does not exist

So I want to install/configure my info files directory. I am using emacs 24.5.1 on Archlinux.

According to [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/info-file-emacs-does-not-exist) I should have my info files located under `export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/share/info/emacs-24`. But it does not load my info files, and the directory `/usr/share/info/emacs-24` does not exist. I notice, however, that I have numerous `*.info.gz` files under, such as the following:

```
/usr/share/info/flymake.info.gz
/usr/share/info/forms.info.gz
/usr/share/info/gnus.info.gz
/usr/share/info/emacs-gnutls.info.gz
/usr/share/info/emacs.info.gz
/usr/share/info/emacs-mime.info.gz
```

The complete file listing is listed here: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/emacs/files/ which includes many more `*.info.gz` files under `/usr/share/info/`. How can I make these files accessible to my emacs distro? Should I make the directory `/usr/share/info/emacs-24` and unzip the files in there? Or is there an elpa package that I am missing?

Any help would be great.

---

*UPDATE*

Interestingly, if I run `M-x dired RET /usr/share/gnus.info.gz`, then I can open the info manual. But how can I execute a function like `(info "(gnus) Sorting the Summary Buffer")`?

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the variables `Info-directory-list` and `Info-default-directory-list` was very helpful. It turns out that I needed to add `export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/share/info` to my `~/.bashrc`, reboot my pc, and it works!

Apparently `Info-directory-list` is created when emacs boots with the contents of `INFOPATH`, but I needed to restart my pc to get `INFOPATH` readable by emacs. `C-h v Info-directory-list` was very helpful in learning more about this issue.

Update: a logout/login would probably have been sufficient over a full reboot.